# How i can disable showing the status bar while activity is full Screen?

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately, I was unable to find an answer to this topic by searching on topics of various topics.
I want to take full screen activity and prevent status bar from displaying the load when dragged.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: What is meant by "displaying the load". Android supports dragging full-screen windows (like in Windows how one can be "torn" out of full screen by dragging on the title)?

Comment: Have you tried setting the activity's theme attribute in the manifest to the NoTitleBar theme (`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (put it in your Activity class):

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Comment: You do not fully understand my question; my activity is fullscreen and I want to disable the statusbar when drag.

Comment: @MajidRajabiVardanjani Posting screens and code snippets helps reduce this kind of confusion... If your Activity is full screen, then how can it be dragged?